# How to open a file from folder where EXE was opened. VB

Tags: vb.net

Part of a program I am making  I need to open a file (for example a txt file) from the folder where the program was opened.
The idea is that it can be zipped up and put anywhere without having to place the file in a certain location.
It's got to be Visual Basic and I will really appreciate some help.

I have googled this but found nothing for VB. I'm relatively new to the language.

Thanks, Jack

Comment: Just a heads up in case you move this direction, but if you ever end up installing this as a program in the Program Files folder, standard user accounts have not had write access to the Program Files folder since Windows 2000. For some reason this still catches programmers by surprise all the time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah thanks. It's going to be a standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the file do this:

```
Dim fileName as String = "yourfile.txt"
Dim appDir as String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)

Process.Start(appDir & "\" & fileName)
```

Comment: So if someone wanted to open another application (e.g iexplorer.exe or a batch file) would you just edit the file name and not open it as a string then?

Comment: Don't worry I understand the code. It opens the file as a string named file name and then is opened at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the path to the folder where the currently executing assembly (i.e. the EXE) is located:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Substring(0, assembly.Location.LastIndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
```